# What are the methods which are used to increase the performance of AWS Elasticsearch service?

Tags: performance, amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, aws-elasticsearch

What are the methods used for the performance enhancement of **AWS Elasticsearch** in general?
How can I achieve that?

How many **Data instances** and **Dedicated master instances** are ideal for my app when the storage I provided is **10 GB**.

Can anyone explain to me how can I increase the performance of searching and putting in elastic search?

Comment: What performance issues are you having? Indexing or Searching?

Comment: @leandrojmp I have issues in both. Saving the data into Elasticsearch also takes time(which we are doing through DSL put queries and Getting also). I just want to know what are the various methods used for increasing performance in general.

Comment: This [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/tune-for-indexing-speed.html) has tips to improve the indexing speed, and this other [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/tune-for-search-speed.html) has tipos to improve query speed, read them and see if you can apply anything to your deployment.